# Why mysql query in groovy returns empty

Tags: mysql, groovy

lst is a list of table_names

```
for (el in lst) {
     //println el
    sql.eachRow("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS"
        + " WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'"
        + " AND table_name = ?"
        + " AND COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI'", [el]) {
        lst1.add("${it.COLUMN_NAME}")
   }
}
```

- I have tried using tablename=: table_name [table_name: el] in the WHERE clause

It works when I run the sql.eachRow outside the for loop and manually supply the tablename

Any ideas on how I can make this work is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer table_name = '${el}' and remove , [el].